# 3dtouch to present(peek without pop) UIView like contacts app

Tags: ios, 3dtouch

I'm trying to implement 3D Touch feature that presents a summary of information (like Peek). But I don't want that it pops. I just want to preview the information like contacts app does with contatcs:

[image]

It only presents an UIView and doesn't deal with two levels of force (peek and pop).

How can I do something like this?

Ps.: I don't want to deal with long press gesture.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: No. You can't do this. Its a native behaviour for contacts.

Answer (score 0):

### Introduction

Hello

I know this is a bit to late, probably, but in case someone else stumbles upon it: I certainly believe it is possible and I don't think its a "native behavior for contacts". Although it would not be as simple as the UIKit api for peek pop views. You would need to:

#### Steps

1. subclass `UIGestureRecognizer` (perhaps it may work with the `UITapGestureRecognizer` also), and register `UITouch`es and use their `force` property.
2. Setup a UIViewController with transparent but blurred background around the edges (together with a modalPresentationStyle `.overCurrentContext` if i recall correctly), with your desired content in the middle (much like the peek view). Then add a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the center view for dismissal/sliding up the buttons.
3. And then create a custom animation transition for that `UIViewController` to be triggered once the `force` property of the registered `UITouches` from the subclassed `UIGestureRecognizer` is high enough. And then reversed once the `force` property gets low enough.

#### Concluding notes

I believe this is a bit of a tedious task and there might be a simpler way. For example, a simpler way using a 3rd party library for long pressure gestures (that registers size of the touch), but it would not give the same feel.